# Sqlalchemy Insert - AttributeError: object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a msyql table with a datetime column. I am trying to use python's datetime.datetime.now() and insert into it with sqlalchemy core.

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, create_engine, Table, insert 
import datetime 
# from sqlalchemy.sql import func
engine = create_engine('...') 
conn = engine.connect() 

tablemeta = MetaData(bind=engine, reflect=True) 

datetime_test_table = Table('datetime_test', tablemeta, autoload=True, 
        autoload_with=engine) 

ins = insert(datetime_test_table).values(datetime.datetime.now()) 
conn.execute(ins)
```

I get the following error :

`AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'items'`

I tried using func.now() as well, but a similar error occurs. What object should I use to do the insertion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Insert.values) on `Insert.values()`

To pass values to an `INSERT` statement, you can use keyword args:

```
users.insert().values(name="some name")
```

Or you can pass a single positional arg:

> a dictionary, tuple, or list of dictionaries or tuples can be passed as a single positional argument

```
users.insert().values({"name": "some name"})  # passing a single dict
users.insert().values((5, "some name"))  # passing a tuple (could be list too).
```

For tuples/lists of values, SQLAlchemy will turn that into a dictionary by iterating over the table columns and the collection of values. This is the function that processes a single positional arg to `.values()` ([permalink](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/c8dea359db9bea58dc64880d306dbee2a26df247/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/dml.py#L38)):

```
def process_single(p):
    if isinstance(p, (list, tuple)):
        return dict(
            (c.key, pval)
            for c, pval in zip(self.table.c, p)
        )
    else:
        return p  # this is where it is assumed that your datetime object is a dict
```

So, it's documented that your single positional arg to `.values()` can be any of a `dict`, `list` or `tuple` and in the above function, you can see that if you pass a `list` or `tuple` of values, they are converted into a `dict`. If your single positional arg *is not* a `list` or `tuple`, it is simply returned, under the assumption that it is a `dict` (I've annotated where that assumption is made in the example above).

This is what brings about your error. You are passing a single positional arg to `.values()` that is neither a `list` or `tuple`, so SQLAlchemy assumes it is a `dict`. But, it's not a `dict`, it's a `datetime.datetime` instance. The error...

```
AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'items'
```

...is simply the first time that SQLAlchemy performs a `dict` specific operation on your parameter object after making the assumption that it is a `dict`.

To fix your issue, simply pass the values in an acceptable format, any of these will do:

```
ins = insert(datetime_test_table).values((datetime.datetime.now(),))
ins = insert(datetime_test_table).values([datetime.datetime.now()])
ins = insert(datetime_test_table).values({'dt_col_name': datetime.datetime.now()})
ins = insert(datetime_test_table).values(dt_col_name=datetime.datetime.now())
```